# How to convert RefMut<T> to Ref<T>

Tags: rust, interior-mutability

I was wondering if it's possible to convert a `RefMut<T>` to a `Ref<T>` in Rust?

Some context - Inside of a function, I've used `.borrow_mut()` to access an item in a `RefCell<T>` mutably, and now want to return an immutable reference to it from the function. I believe I cannot use `&T` as it would be a temporary value than cannot be returned from the function, though correct me if I'm wrong.

If not, I'd love to know the technical reason why it's not possible.

Comment: You can obtain a `&mut T`, then reborrow it as `&T`, no `Ref` necessary.

Comment: (Edited the post for clarity) I believe I cannot use `&T` as it would be a temporary value than cannot be returned from the function, though correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Null You are correct.

Comment: Perhaps you could however return `impl Deref<Target = T>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to prevent mutation through `RefMut` you can give a reference to it, which will "turn off" `DerefeMut` implementation (you won't have access to exclusive reference).

But if you want to "convert" `RefMut` to `Ref`, then I'm afraid it's not possible. The only way is to drop `RefMut` and then `borrow` again. I don't think this is *impossible* pre se. You could imagine a method on `RefMut` that would change reference counters and downgrade a `RefMut` to `Ref`. But there is nothing like this in current standard library.

Comment: Currently it is possible to have multiple `RefMut`s to a single `RefCell` (where each refers to distinct parts thereof, such as different elements of a slice) and this is tracked with a simple counter... converting one such `RefMut` to a `Ref` would require a significant change to the implementation.

Comment: "Currently it is possible to have multiple `RefMut`s to a single `RefCell`" - could you share an example of how is this possible?

Comment: @Cerberus [`RefMut::map_split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html#method.map_split).